# Facebook Graph Search - type=IdInterest, offset Error

Tags: facebook, facebook-graph-api, search, paging

I am trying to get results from Facebook Graph search. I want to get all the results. Facebook has a parameter "limit", that must be 500 or less. So I set it to 500.

like this:
https://graph.facebook.com/search?type=adinterest&q=Linux&limit=500&access_token=ACCESS_TOKEN.

So in order to get the rest of the results, I tried using "offset" parameter. But facebook doesn't get me different results than the first call with the offset.

So how can I get all results for the query?

Answer (score 0):

There doesn't to be any more results from that call. If you believe there should be more results than observed file a bug. https://developers.facebook.com/bugs

Also the correct call is

`search?type=adinterest&q=Linux`

not `adinterests` and not `p`

https://developers.facebook.com/docs/reference/ads-api/get-autocomplete-data/v2.2#interests